# Notify ListView on receiving Dataset

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a ListView that gets its dataset from a BaseAdapter.
The ListView receives data when a menuItem is clicked.
I am not able to notify my listView or my ListAdapter (inboxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()), doesnt work.
Any other approaches.

```
case R.id.Get:
  retrieveList();
  inboxEmails = EmailElement.parseContent();
  inboxAdapter = new nboxAdapter(getApplicationContext(),inboxEmails);
   if(inboxAdapter !=null){
    listView.setAdapter(inboxAdapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    inboxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
break;
```

//this method retrieveList by sending sms

```
private void retrieveList(){
  registerReceiver(new SMSSentReciever(), new IntentFilter(SMSInfo.SENT));
  registerReceiver(new SMSDeliveredReciever(), new IntentFilter(SMSInfo.DELIVERED));
  PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMSInfo.SENT), 0);
  PendingIntent deliveryIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMSInfo.DELIVERED),0);
  SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("5556",null, "fruits", sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
```

}

Based on the message from broadcast i need to update or notify my Listview, for now when i click the  menu firstly i get my message on the emulator and then from the other emulator i send above message, the toast is shown,but not the listview but once i click the menu again i finally get the listview. WHat have i done wrong?

Comment: please check first the data have been updated or not then call the notifyDataSetChanged thanks

Comment: Case R.id.Go:  i have a method which will fetch me all my listView data. Then i check if my adapter is !null, if true then i set my adapter and then noftifyDataSetChanged() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, calling `listView1.setAdapter(adapter)` will force the listview to refresh.

Comment: If you look at the code above, it it as same as you mentioned here. but my problem is firstly i click the menuitem, the toast show us but not the listview and if i click the menuitem once again i see the list view. That's my problem

Comment: Try listView1.requestLayout() or listView1.invalidate(). If those don't work, then take a look at your code and debug it to make sure that the data does actually get changed because at least one of these four methods always work to refresh the listview.

Comment: Still in Vain. My debug has no problems